# Java jdbc MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException and MySQLSyntaxErrorException insert

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, insert, prepared-statement

I have to insert data in a table of a database. For this, I use a preparedStatement like this :

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(200);
Connection co2 = null;
PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
ResultSet rs2 = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    co2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    ps2 = co2.prepareStatement("insert into class" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    ps2.setInt(1, r);
    ps2.setString(2, rs.getString("superClass"));
    ps2.setString(3, "Object");
    ps2.setString(4, null);
    ps2.execute();
    System.out.println("insert passé");
    list.add(rs.getString("superClass"));
} finally {
    close(co2, ps2, rs2);
}
```

The database has a table "class" which has 4 columns : idClass (bigInt), name (String), superClass (String) and package (String).

When I execute this part of code I have a

`MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails FOREIGN KEY (idClass)`

I don't know why but the database has a table "typeclass" which has exactly the same columns and data of the class table and I think I have to insert the same query in "typeclass". So I test this :

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(200);
Connection co2 = null;
PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
ResultSet rs2 = null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    co2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
    ps2 = co2.prepareStatement("insert into class" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)" + "insert into typeclass" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    ps2.setInt(1, r);
    ps2.setString(2, rs.getString("superClass"));
    ps2.setString(3, "Object");
    ps2.setString(4, null);
    ps2.setInt(5, r);
    ps2.setString(6, rs.getString("superClass"));
    ps2.setString(7, "Object");
    ps2.setString(8, null);
    ps2.execute();
    System.out.println("insert passé");
    list.add(rs.getString("superClass"));
    } finally {
        close(co2, ps2, rs2);
    }
```

But now I have a

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException near "insert into typeclass values (174, "JFrame", "Object", null)"
```

I don't know where is the problem, can you help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Maybe you have to check your data model and understand it first of all. It seems by your description and errors that there is a relation between tables class and typeclass represented by idClass as a foreign key in class pointing to typeclass. If so, you got to insert (or check if it is present already) a record in typeclass and after that insert your desired record in class. That has to be made in two separated PreparedStatement objects, one per SQL insert.

Comment: The first error means you're trying to insert a value in column `idClass` that has no corresponding entry in the foreign key target. The second error simply means that you can't just concatenate two insert queries and hope that gets them to work: you'll need to prepare and execute those separately!